# Is there an equivalent field in Tfs_Analysis OLAP cube for the dimIteration.StartDate from the Tfs_Warehouse DB?

Tags: reporting-services, olap

I'm converting an SSRS report that currently hits the Tfs_Warehouse relational DB and we want it to use the Tfs_Analysis OLAP cube instead.

The report uses the dbo.dimIteration.StartDate field from the Tfs_Warehouse DB, I can't find it in the cube...

Anyone knows how it's called or how to find it in the TFS cube?